# Is this way of using dictionary correct to store product info and apply calculations

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, dictionary

I have a dictionary object containing product names and corresponding prices:

```
            var products = new List<Dictionary<string, decimal>>()
            {
                new Dictionary<string, decimal> {{"product1", 10}},
                new Dictionary<string, decimal> {{"product2", 20}},
                new Dictionary<string, decimal> {{"product3", 30}}
            };
```

I then loop through this and apply some calculations per product:

```
        foreach (var product in products)
        {
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, decimal> kvp in product)
            {
               var result = GetRatePerProduct(kvp.Key) * kvp.Value;        
            }
        }
```

**GetRatePerProduct** simply takes the productname and returns a decimal rate.

Based on this loop the calculated results will be inserted into orders table which contains a column per product, Product1, Product2, Product3...

So after the loop the table should look like this:

```
Product1 Product2 Product3 ...
12       24       36
```

I thought about creating another dictionary like this:

```
var results = new List<Dictionary<string, decimal>>();
```

and populating it within the for loop and then outside the loop use this dictionary to insert the data into SQL database. **I have shortened the number of products in this example, but we will have 52 products, this number will never change.**

Is this approach right? Is there a better way of doing this, possibly using Linq? Can you point to me into the right direction in terms of doing this with Linq?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing particularly wrong with the way you have done it, though there are lots of other options.
In c# you can easily use Linq for that sort of operation, and you could also very easily parallelize the operation.

You have the question tagged with 'sql-server-2008' which makes me wonder whether the data for this operation is coming from a database. If so it may be more efficient to do the work in SQL  rather than in C#.

So in answer to your two questions:

Is this approach right? - it is certainly not wrong.

Is there a better way of doing this? - there are other ways, but whether they are better depends on factors not mentioned in the question.

... more:
I've come up with two linq-ish approaches. The first preserves your data structures:

```
        var products = new List<Dictionary<string, decimal>>()
        {
            new Dictionary<string, decimal> {{"product1", 10}},
            new Dictionary<string, decimal> {{"product2", 20}},
            new Dictionary<string, decimal> {{"product3", 30}}
        };
        var results = new List<Dictionary<string, decimal>>();

        results.AddRange(products.Select(product =>
        {
            var resultDictionary = new Dictionary<string, decimal>();
            foreach (string key in product.Keys)
            {
                resultDictionary.Add(key, GetRatePerProduct(key));
            }
            return resultDictionary;
        }));
```

The second makes a new Product class to cover the three properties you are working with, but does the same work with them.

```
    public class Product
    {
        public string ProductName { get; set; }
        public decimal ProductValue { get; set; }
        public decimal ProductResult { get; set; }
    }

        var products = new List<Product>()
        {
            new Product () {ProductName = "product1", ProductValue = 10},
            new Product () {ProductName = "product2", ProductValue = 20},
            new Product () {ProductName = "product3", ProductValue = 30},
        };

        var results = new List<Dictionary<string, decimal>>();

        foreach (var product in products)
        {
            product.ProductValue = GetRatePerProduct(product.ProductName);
        }

        // the next two lines do exactly the same thing, just one of them is explicitly parallelized
        products.ForEach(product => { product.ProductValue = GetRatePerProduct(product.ProductName); });
        Parallel.ForEach(products, product => { product.ProductValue = GetRatePerProduct(product.ProductName); });
```

Comment: Thanks, the calculation has to be done in C#, doing it on SQL unfortunately is not an option (business reasons). I was actually wondering how to do this with Linq but not sure as my Linq knowledge is not enough for the moment.

Comment: OK, the more I look at this the more I have to ask: Why do you have a list of Dictionaries where each Dictionary has only one key-value pair?

Comment: You are quite right, a single dictionary with multiple key value pairs would be better. No need to put the dictionary in a list. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No reason to use dictionary objects if you are only going to use it to store one key - value pair.

Much better solution is to create a class Products that has properties Name and Price and then to add those objects to the list.